# Find all tags of certain class only after tag with certain text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a big long table in an HTML, so the tags aren't nested within each other.  It looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="x">...</td>
    <td class="x">...</td>
    <td class="x">...</td>
    <td class="x">...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class ="y">...</td>
    <td class ="y">...</td>
    <td class ="y">...</td>
    <td class ="y">...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="x">...</td>
    <td class="x">...</td>
    <td class="x">...</td>
    <td class="x">...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class ="y">I want this</td>
    <td class ="y">and this</td>
    <td class ="y">and this</td>
    <td class ="y">and this</td>
</tr>
```

So first I want to search the tree to find "B".  Then I want to grab the text of every td tag with class y after B but before the next row of table starts over with "C".

I've tried this:

```
results = soup.find_all('td')
for result in results:
    if result.string == "B":
        print(result.string)
```

This gets me the string B that I want.  But now I am trying to find all after this and I'm not getting what I want.

```
for results in soup.find_all('td'):
    if results.string == 'B':
        a = results.find_next('td',class_='y')
```

This gives me the next td after the 'B', which is what I want, but I can only seem to get that first td tag.  I want to grab all of the tags that have class y, after 'B' but before 'C' (C isn't shown in the html, but follows the same pattern), and I want to it to a list.

My resulting list would be:

```
[['I want this'],['and this'],['and this'],['and this']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need to locate the element containing `B` text. This is your starting point.

Then, check every `tr` sibling of this element using [`find_next_siblings()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
start = soup.find("td", text="B").parent
for tr in start.find_next_siblings("tr"):
    # exit if reached C
    if tr.find("td", text="C"):
        break

    # get all tds with a desired class
    tds = tr.find_all("td", class_="y")
    for td in tds:
        print(td.get_text())
```

Tested on your example data, it prints:

```
I want this
and this
and this
and this
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It works for me.  But, I got lucky because what I need is the last in the siblings every time.  Since I don't really know what 'C' is going to be, and would rather his be dynamic, how can I make this better so it works regardless.  So, instead of breaking out of that iteration of the loop if the text is 'C', how can I check that it's not equal to 'B'.